# Hugin compiling instruction?

Tags: cmake

I have download the lasted Hugin source code from this following link [sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/p/hugin/hugin/ci/default/tree/) read README file in the source code.

Go through several instruction and `guide Build_Hugin_for_Windows_with_SDK` and `Hugin_Compiling_Windows`, etc. and I am still clueless at what I should do to compile the source code using CMake. I have no experience using CMake, neither the instructions nor README file did help me much. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout their `INSTALL_cmake` next to the `README` which states clearly:

> ```
> cd hugin
> mkdir mybuild
> cd mybuild
> cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ../
> make
> make install
> ```